# Why am I getting an assertion error with my gulp 4 gulp.js

Tags: npm, gulp, gulp-sass

I'm trying to get gulp running on Windows 7.

I've downloaded `npm (6.4.1)`

Installed `gulp(CLI version 3.9.1 , Local version 4.0.0)`

I have done the `npm init` in the theme file.

But I get

> assert.js:351
>       throw err;
>       ^ AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified

Looking at similar errors I decide to change gulp.js from:

```
gulp.task('browser-sync', ['sass'], function() {
    browserSync.init({
        proxy: "local.mysite.co:8080",
        notify: true
    });
});
```

to:

```
gulp.task('browser-sync', gulp.series( 'sass', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        proxy: "local.mysite.co:8080",
        notify: true
    });
}));
```

But I now get:

> assert.js:351
>       throw err;
>       ^ AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task never defined: sass

Comment: I switched to gulp@3.3.4 and it runs. I'm just not sure why the changes to gulp.js for gulp 4.x don't work.

Comment: Your 'sass' task must be defined before you call it in your 'browser-sync' task.  I bet that was the problem.

Comment: Any update, did my suggestion in the comment help?

Answer (score 2):

Usually the error `Task never defined:` upon migrating from gulp3 to gulp4 means that you are calling a task before it has been registered.

In your case, I bet that the '`browser-sync`' task below is defined before the '`sass`' task.

```
gulp.task('browser-sync', gulp.series( 'sass', function() {
```

Just move your `gulp.task('sass', ………)` to before the '`browser-sync`' task.

Or change to the new function notation, like:

```
function sass() {
  return gulp.src(paths.sass.stylesFile)
    .pipe(sass().on("error", sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.css.temp))
    .pipe(reload({ stream: true }));
}
```

and the order is less of a problem.  But there are other changes to make as well if you go this route.  It is not necessary to do so - you could just move your `sass` task as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Removed `node_modules` folder within the project folder. In terminal(in the project folder) run this:

```
npm install gulp --save-dev .
```

Now it works

Comment: And when you run "gulp -v" on the command line what do you get?

Comment: `postcss-playground gulp -v
[11:15:04] CLI version 2.0.1
[11:15:04] Local version 3.9.1`

Comment: Yes you are running gulp version 3.9.1.  The OP's syntax works fine with 3.9.1 but not with 4.